# Chaining Promises without using multiple "then's"

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, cheerio

I'm learning how to use Promises.  I have the following functions that returns the "i"th xkcd comic title as a Promise:

```js
var xkcd = function(i) {
  return new Promise(
    function(resolve, reject) {
      var tempurl = 'https://www.xkcd.com/' + i;
      request(tempurl, function(error, response, body) {
        if (error) reject(error);
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);
        resolve($('title').text() + '\n');
      });
    });
};
```

If i want to get the first 4 titles, I'm chaining my .then() as such:

```js
var result = '';
xkcd(1)
  .then(fullfilled => {
    result += fullfilled;
  })
  .then(() => xkcd(2))
  .then(fullfilled => {
    result += fullfilled;
  })
  .then(() => xkcd(3))
  .then(fullfilled => {
    result += fullfilled;
  })
  .then(() => xkcd(4))
  .then(fullfilled => {
    result += fullfilled;
    console.log(result);
  });
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this without chaining this many "then"s? Say if i want to get the first 50 comic titles, i'll have to chain a lot of "then"s.

I can do it without using Promises using recursive callbacks:

```js
function getXKCD(n) {
  var i = 1;
  (function getURL(i){
    var tempurl = 'https://www.xkcd.com/' + i;
    request(tempurl, function(error, response, body) {
      if (error) console.log('error: ' + error);
      var $ = cheerio.load(body);
      //prints the title of the xkcd comic
      console.log($('title').text() + '\n');
      i++;
      if (i <= n) getURL(i);
    });
  })(i);
}

getXKCD(4);
```

But I'm interested to know if I can do the same with Promises.  Thank you.

Comment: Look at `Promise.all`

Comment: the question is do you need to receive the articles sequentially or all at once?

Comment: Also, you you don't have to put `result += fullfilled;` in its own `.then()`.  You can just call the next function in the same `.then()`.  Cut almost half of them that way.  But, if these don't have to be run serially, then you can run them all at once and use `Promise.all()` to collect all the results.

Comment: @zzzzBov yep, looks like Promise.all will be able to do what i want, thanks.

Comment: You can also do it recursively with promises.

Comment: Btw, [XKCD has a JSON API](https://xkcd.com/json.html). No need for Cheerio :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get the articles sequentially:

```
function getSequentially(currentArticle, doUntil) {
  if (currentArticle !== doUntil) {
    xkcd(currentArticle)
      .then(article => getSequentially(currentArtile + 1, doUntil))
  }
}
```

If you want to get all articles at once:

```
Promise
  .all(new Array(AMOUNT_OF_ARTICLES).fill(null).map((nll, i) => xkcd(i + 1)))
  .then(allArticles => ...);
```

I don't pretend that all above will work right after the copy / paste, this is just an idea of how you can perform this.

Comment: thanks, I think i can get both to work.  The recursive function is great idea.

Comment: Protip: `Array.from({length: AMOUNT_OF_ARTICLES}, (_, i) => …)` is shorter, faster, and less ugly

Comment: @smnbrrv, Is there one for horizontal chaining? https://stackoverflow.com/q/46762491/632951

Answer (score 4):

You can push the promises to an array, and then return `Promise.all`, which would resolve when all the promises have resolved, something like

```
function getXKCD(_start, _end) {
  if (_end >= _start) return Promise.reject('Not valid!');
  var promises = [];

  (function rec(i) {
    var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      request('https://www.xkcd.com/' + i, function(error, response, body) {
        if (error !== null) return reject(error);

        if (i <= _end) rec(++i);
        let $ = cheerio.load(body);
        resolve($('title').text());
      });
    });

    promises.push(p);
  })(_start);

  return Promise.all(promises);
}

getXKCD(1, 50).then(res => { /* All done ! */ }).catch( err => { /* fail */ })
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like Promise.all is what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways. You can fill an array with all the values you need, and then use a `.map()` with `Promise.all()` or a `.reduce()` so they happen sequentially:

```
function getXkcd(count) {
  // Make an array of the comic numbers using ES6 Array.fill()...
  var ids = new Array(count).fill(1).map((val, index)=>index+1)

  // Now you can .map() or .reduce() over this list.
}
```

There are other interesting ways you can approach this, too. You can use a recursive wrapper to do the work. Leaving your original `xkcd` function intact, you can build a simple function that recursively calls itself...

```
function getXkcd(max, last) {

    var current = last ? last + 1 : 1;

    xkcd(current)
    .then(function(title) {
        // Process the data.
        result += title;
        // We don't really care about a return value, here.
    })
    .then(getXkcd.bind(null, max, current))
    .catch(function(error) {
        // We should do something to let you know if stopped.
    });
}
```

This is pretty close to your callback version. The only real difference is we are using `bind` to pass the current and max values instead of a closure. This does have the benefit that it automatically handles starting from the middle: `getXkcd(50, 15);` That could be added to your callback example, too.

Using a closure lets us keep the state and create a recursive call that's maybe a little cleaner:

```
function getXKCD(max, start) {

    var result = "";

    var getNext = function(id){

        // If we are done, return the result
        if (id > n) {
            return result;
        }

        // Otherwise, keep going.
        return xkcd(id)
        .then(function(title){
            // Accumulate the title in our closure result
            result += title;
            // Send next value
            return id + 1;
        })
        .then(getNext);
    }

    // Kick off the loop
    return getNext(start || 1);
}

getXKCD(50).then(function(results){
    // Do something with the results
}, function(error){
    // Tell us what went wrong
});
```

Inside `getXKCD` we create a function `getNext` that calls itself at the end of the Promise chain. It works like a reducer, serializing the requests, and eventually returns the collected results. This one doesn't use bind, but accepts the "next value" from the previous step in the chain.

Answer (score 0):

Using `async-await` is the nicest way, IMO:

```
   (async () => {
     const result = '';
     for(let i = 1; i < 50; i++) {
       result += await xkcd(i);
     }
     return result
   })().then(result => console.log(result))
```