# Javascript: horizontal chaining promises without multiple then calls

Tags: javascript

Is there a short inbuilt way to do horizontal promise chaining?

The usual way to chain steps is:

```
(async()=>1)().then(_=>{
  //etc..
  return _+_
}).then(_=>{
  //etc..
  return _*_
}).then(_=>{
  //etc..
  return alert(_) // alert 4
})
```

So I use a helper to avoid repeating `then`:

```
F=(...args)=>{
  let p=args[0]
  for(let x=1; x<args.length;++x){
    p=p.then(args[x])
  }
}

F((async()=>1)(), _=>{
  //etc..
  return _+_
}, _=>{
  //etc..
  return _*_
}, _=>{
  //etc..
  return alert(_)
})
```

Another variation that overloads prototype and allows for second argument of then:

```
Promise.prototype.thenAll = function(...args){
  let p = this;
  args.forEach(_=>p=p.then(_[0], _[1]))
}

;(async()=>1)().thenAll([_=>{
  //etc..
  return _+_
}], [_=>{
  //etc..
  return _*_
}], [_=>{
  //etc..
  return alert(_)
}])
```

But is there an inbuilt way to do something akin to these?

Comment: No. You’d have to write your own helper. However haven you considered using async/await instead?

Comment: @FelixKling OP is already using async, without await and the comma operator at the pattern, though is missing parentheses surrounding the expression, and the expression should be with IIAF function body.

Comment: What is the purpose of `async` at code at Question?

Comment: There is no built-in functionality that does this but look at async.waterfall from async-q

Comment: @slebetman OP is already using the built-in functionality - the comma operator

Comment: @guest271314: The comma separator won't work. The OP is not trying to do multiple synchronous operations but multiple async operation. Unless the OP completely misunderstands what Promises are for and is using them on synchronous operations I'm assuming the code above are not the real code the OP wants to run.

Comment: @slebetman Those operations are possible using comma operator with `await` within `async` function. See Answer

Comment: @guest271314: The OP is not trying to run those operations. The real operations the OP wants to run are likely something like `getUsers` and `getUserData` and `checkIfUserIsAdmin`

Comment: @slebetman Yes, that would be three `await`s with `comma` operators before the `alert()` call, as demonstrated at Answer. Find it interesting when  requirements are inserted into the code at Question that do not appear at code at Question.

Comment: @slebetman How do you know what "The real operations" are if not present at text of Question? Does stackoverflow.com/help/mcve not apply? In any event the code at Question is equivalent to `(async(_) => (_ = await _, _ = await Promise.resolve(_++) * await Promise.resolve(_ * _), alert(_)))(Promise.resolve(1))`, where each `Promise.resolve()` can be substituted for a function call which returns a `Promise`

Comment: @OP, guest271314 is right. What are you actually trying to solve? If you are trying to use promises with synchronous operations then you're doing it wrong. Please provide a more realistic example code with your question.

Comment: @guest271314, `(async()=>foobar)()` is short for `Promise.resolve(foobar)`, they mean the same thing.

Comment: @Pacerier _"`(async()=>foobar)()` is short for `Promise.resolve(foobar)`, they mean the same thing. "_ No, the code is not the same. An `async` function allows use of `await`, `Promise.resolve()` alone does not provide that functionality.

Comment: @guest271314, True its one-sided: `Promise.resolve(foobar)` can be written as `(async()=>foobar)()` for 100% of cases, but not the other way round.

Comment: @slebetman, Ok I added `//etc..` in the question to make it clear.

Comment: @FelixKling, Hmm, seems like even with `await`, a helper function is needed.

Comment: @Pacerier The code at Question contains exactly one value that is a resolved `Promise`, though `.then()` returns a new `Promise` object, given that the function at code at Question adds and multiplies the same original `Promise` value, a number, there is no need for two `.then()`s or two function calls where the original value is passed as an argument. Once the `Promise` value is a `Number`, perform the addition and multiplication. The code includes two `.then()`s which are not necessary given the expected result.

Comment: @guest271314, Yea it can be combined into one function, but keeping them separate is the whole point. It looks like the multiple `then`s on https://archive.is/X0G9y#selection-3287.404-3287.491

Comment: @Pacerier _"Yea it can be combined into one function, but keeping them separate is the whole point."_ The whole point of what? The requirement at Question is _"Is there a short inbuilt way to do horizontal promise chaining?"_. Not sure how the link at previous comment is related to the Question? Note, no clear problem statement actually exists within text of Question.

Comment: @guest271314, Right, in an attempt to SSCCE, looks like I had left out the first requirements.

Comment: @Pacerier What is "SSCCE"?

Answer (score 3):

As others have said there is no built in way to do this. The following code might be of interest though.

There is a concept known as 'lifting' whereby you transform a function into one that works on wrapped values. In this case promises. It would look something like this:

```
const lift = (fn) => (promise) => promise.then(fn);
```

There is also the idea of chaining together a list of functions, composing them with one another. Like this:

```
const chain = (...fns) => (value) => fns.reduce((result, fn) => fn(result), value)
```

Together, these tools allow you to rewrite your code as:

```
chain(
  lift(_=>++_),
  lift(_=>_*=_),
  lift(_=>alert(_))
)((async()=>1)())
```

Which alerts 4 as expected.

I'm also a little confused by your use of `++_` and `_*=_` because they imply you wish to mutate the variable. Because of how your code is structured it would be a better display of intent to use `_+1` and `_*_`

Comment: This sort of function composition can be incredibly useful in some projects, +1

Comment: @david, Yes for the code above `_*_` would work the same way as `_ *= _`

Answer (score 1):

Using [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), you can combine the series of functions into a promise chain using the following static function:

```js
function series (initial, ...callbacks) {
  return callbacks.reduce(
    (chain, callback) => chain.then(callback),
    Promise.resolve(initial)
  )
}

series(1, _=>_+1, _=>_*_, alert)
```

For convenience, you could define this as `Promise.series()` like this:

```
Object.defineProperty(Promise, 'series', {
  configurable: true,
  value: function series (initial, ...callbacks) { ... },
  writable: true
})
```

Lastly, in ES2017, you could alternatively use [`async` / `await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) to write it like this:

```js
async function series(initial, ...callbacks) {
  let value = await initial

  for (const callback of callbacks) {
    value = await callback(value)
  }

  return value
}

series(1, _=>_+1, _=>_*_, alert)
```

Comment: I see it looks like there's no in-built way then. Btw that use of `async function series` is cool

Answer (score 1):

You can use rest parameter to pass `N` functions to a function which return a `Promise` to be called in sequence with the previous `Promise` value set to parameter passed to the current function call until no elements remain in array using `async/await` and repeated scheduling of the same procedure

```js
const a = n => new Promise(resolve => 
  setTimeout(resolve, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000), ++n));

const b = n => new Promise(resolve => 
  setTimeout(resolve, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000), n * n));

const F = async(n, ...fns) => {
  try {
    while (fns.length) n = await fns.shift()(n);
    alert(n);
  } catch (err) {
    throw err
  }
  return n
}

F(1, a, b)
.then(n => console.log(n))
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: Note, the code at Answer could also be used as a function returned from a single `.then()` `Promise.resolve(1).then(async(n) => { let res = await F(n, a, b); console.log(res)})` or use an alternative `async/await` pattern `(async() => { let n = await Promise.resolve(1); n = await F(n, a, b); console.log(n); return n})()`

Answer (score -1):

Given that the code at Question is synchronous you can use the code at Question

```js
((_) => (_++, _*=_, alert(_)) )(1)
```

Or use `async/await`

```js
(async(_) => (_ = await _, _++, _ *= _, alert(_)))(Promise.resolve(1))
```

Comment: Note, the code at Answer meets requirement precisely. You can include more `await`s between comma operators if necessary

Comment: Yea I upvoted this, but the whole point is that each step is a standalone function,.

Comment: @Pacerier _"the whole point is that each step is a standalone function,."_ does not appear at text of original Question. The actual question is _"is there an inbuilt way to do something akin to this?"_. The Answer is yes, using `async/await` and comma operator

Comment: Ok I added `//etc..` in the code to make it clear that there's more to it that's removed.

Comment: @Pacerier There is not "more to it". The code at Answer proves that the answer is yes, using comma operator and `await`